# How to find the nearest lat and lang in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am trying find the nearest lang and lat from the specified lat and lang
i tried the below mentioned query, in my query i have mentioned the place muscat's lat and lang ,so i want to display the nearest cities of muscat with limit 3 along with muscat

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(_id SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,city VARCHAR, Lat NUMERIC, Lang NUMERIC);

select * from (
SELECT  *,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(6.414478) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lang ) - radians(12.466646) ) + sin( radians(6.414478) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM tablename
) al
where lat >  23.61  OR lang >  58.54
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```

here is my table (Assumed data not exact lat and lang)data

```
| id | City      |  lat      | lang    |
----------------------------------------
|  1 | muscat    | 23.61     | 58.54   |
|  2 | sur       | 22.566    |59.52    |
|  3 | Muhafazat |23.585     |58.40    |
|  4 | ZZZ       | 5.8       | 7       |
|  5 | AAA       | 9.22      | 5       |
|  6 | Barka     |23.613     |58.592   |
```

Expected out put:

```
    | id | City      |  lat      | lang    |
    ----------------------------------------
    |  1 | muscat    | 23.61     | 58.54   |
    |  2 | sur       | 22.566    |59.52    |
    |  3 | Muhafazat |23.585     |58.40    |
    |  6 | Barka     |23.613     |58.592   |
```

Comment: Can you post your table and data as a script so we can run it too? And what is the output from your query?

Comment: Am not getting any data , it retrieved 0 rows even though i have 2-3 relevant values

Comment: With PostGIS this is quite easy: https://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/

Comment: Why don't you use https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i got the output with this query, and thank you to all who tried to help me:)

```
select * from (SELECT  *,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(6.414478) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lang ) - radians(12.466646) ) + sin( radians(6.414478) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table name) al where lat >= 22.566 OR lat >= 59.52 AND lat <= 22.566 OR lat <= 59.52 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Not sure what the `WHERE` clause is trying to do but it's useless.